# Can explode in PHP help me split by two factors?

Tags: php

The usual:

```
$data = 'hello world&cool&stuff&here';

$explode = explode('&', $data); // returns array with hello world, cool, stuff, here
```

Now this data

```
$data = 'hey this is a beautiful day #content_start#The World is Beautiful#content_end#';
```

How can i extract "The World is Beautiful" from the above string?

Running `explode('#content_start', $data);` and then `explode('#content_end', $data);` ? Or is there an easier and more fit way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you had would work perfectly fine.

Just do it like that:

```
$data = 'hey this is a beautiful day #content_start#The World is Beautiful#content_end#';
$first = explode('#content_start#', $data);
$second = explode('#content_end#', $first[1]);
echo $second[0];
```

The first explode will return an array of strings, where the first (`$first[0]`) will be `hey this is a beautiful day` and the second (`$first[1]`) will be `The World is Beautiful#content_end#`. Then you can use the second explode to have the result you wanted.

---

However, a more readable approach would be to use a RegEx to match your searched pattern and literally search for your string. The code would then be:

```
$data = 'hey this is a beautiful day #content_start#The World is Beautiful#content_end#';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/#content_start#(.*)#content_end#/', $data, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try THIS....

```
$data = 'hey this is a beautiful day #content_start#The World is Beautiful#content_end#';
echo substr(strstr(implode(explode("end#",implode("{",explode("start#", implode(explode("#content_", $data)))))), '{'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using this?

```
$data = 'hey this is a beautiful day #content_start#The World is Beautiful#content_end#';
$parts = explode('#', $data);
echo $parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `explode` is not the best option here.

You should better use `strpos` and `substr`:

```
$start = '#content_start#';
$end   = '#content_end#';
$startPos = strpos($data, $start) + strlen($start);
$length = strpos($data, $end) - $startPos;
$result = substr($data, $startPos, $length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for regular expressions:

```
$data = 'hey this is a beautiful day #content_start#The World is Beautiful#content_end#';
preg_match( '/#content_start#(.*)#content_end#/s', $data, $matches );
print_r( $matches );
```

This will display:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #content_start#The World is Beautiful#content_end#
    [1] => The World is Beautiful
)
```

So `$matches[0]` contains the original matched string, and `$matches[1]` contains the match.